# Comparing records from different tables with slightly different data

Tags: sql, compare

I have two tables. Each table has product information and a price. I would like to be able to get results which show the product name and both prices.
However, the product name in each table is written slightly differently. e.g.

Table 1

```
Name                       Price            Pack Size
Aciclovir 200 mg Tablets     3.50             25
Aciclovir 400 mg Tablets     4.20             56
Aciclovir 800 mg Tablets     5.40             35
ACICLOVIR CREAM              2.40             GM
```

Table 2

```
ACICLOVIR 200MG TABs           1              25
ACICLOVIR 200MG TABs           1              25
ACICLOVIR 400MG TABs           2              56
Aciclovir 5% Cream  2gm        2.30           na
```

I've tried with `LIKE`, but I'm not really getting the results that I need.

Comment: So in both tables there is a name of a product and its strength (mg). The name is always at the start of the string, but the strength could be anywhere in the string, Is there anyway to extract the name and the strength together in both tables using inStr ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case (and in SQL Server), I can suggest you to use this:

```
REPLACE(a.Name, ' ', '') LIKE REPLACE(REPLACE(b.Name, ' ' ,''), 'TABs', 'TAB%s')
OR 
REPLACE(b.Name, ' ' ,'') LIKE REPLACE(REPLACE(a.Name, ' ', ''), 'CREAM', '%CREAM%')
```

---

I can simply tell you when you have something that is changing remove it from your compare when you want to ignore a `' '` remove it and so on. when a `MG` is changing you can also remove it in your compare, I remove this ignore texts by using `REPLACE()`.

Comment: Ok, How about if I want to just find the value of mg in the product name? mg could be anywhere within the string, but will always be preceded by a space and will always have a space after...

Answer (score 0):

> Use **trim** where ever possible to remove spaces. This will help you
>   to make the column value similar.
>
> For Example- 800 mg and 800MG .. by using trim you can get this same
>   value then use them in your query

Comment: Also try not to enter full keyword in like query... because it wont match